Can a PFC converter work if input AC voltage is distorted (having harmonics)?
I see the assumption that the input AC volatge is clean (pure AC), in almost all PFC explanation articles.
What if the input AC has some harmonics, say a volatge distortion factor of 10%, would it anyway affect the PFC operation? I see the inner current loop is fast responding, hence would the harmonics in input voltage cause instability?


Image source:Ref 2

Power factor is well defined for non-sinusoidal waveforms, too.  PF → 1 does indeed replicate the voltage waveform in the current waveform.
I don't have any examples to hand right now, but I can confirm having seen it in practice.  Mains voltage in my area has a slight tilted flat to the peaks, I don't know what THD exactly, but it is visible on the oscilloscope.

So if there is a distortion in volatge waveform ( eg: tilt), the same will be replicated by PFC control circuit in current waveform as well, Correct?

@Dynamic_equilibrium Yes
